# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value; SELECT same row twice with different conditions;

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to run the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_pin AS Pin, att_date AS DailyDate,
    (SELECT MAX(att_time) FROM dbo.att_transaction WHERE att_state = 0 GROUP BY person_pin) 
    AS MaxTime,
    (SELECT MIN(att_time) FROM dbo.att_transaction WHERE att_state = 1 GROUP BY person_pin) 
    AS MinTime
FROM dbo.att_transaction
WHERE att_verify IN (4, 15)
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

When I run the query without the: GROUP BY person_pin
it runs without error but I get the following result:

[image]

It gets the min or max value for the whole column.

I need it to get the min and max value per user, per day.

But the min value should only be gotten from rows with its att_state as 0 and the max value for rows with its att_state as 1.

The table I'm querying looks like this:

```
id  person_pin  att_date     att_time     att_state
---|-----------|------------|------------|---------
1  | 123       | 2018-09-18 | 15:11:03   | 1 
2  | 123       | 2018-09-18 | 10:05:32   | 0
5  | 234       | 2018-09-24 | 14:05:16   | 1
3  | 234       | 2018-09-24 | 13:05:55   | 1
4  | 123       | 2018-09-24 | 12:10:42   | 0
6  | 123       | 2018-09-24 | 12:15:35   | 0
7  | 234       | 2018-09-24 | 12:05:32   | 1
8  | 123       | 2018-09-24 | 10:05:33   | 1
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tt.person_pin AS Pin, tt.att_date AS DailyDate
FROM dbo.att_transaction tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT person_pin,
    (SELECT MAX(att_time) FROM dbo.att_transaction WHERE att_state = 0 GROUP BY person_pin) 
    AS MaxTime,
    (SELECT MIN(att_time) FROM dbo.att_transaction WHERE att_state = 1 GROUP BY person_pin) 
    AS MinTime
    FROM dbo.att_transaction
    GROUP BY person_pin) groupedtt 
ON tt.person_pin = groupedtt.person_pin
```

But it only returns:

[image]

I need it to return the min and max time per day, per user.
But the min time should only be gotten from rows with att_state as 0
and the max time should only be gotten from rows with att_state as 1

Need help ;m;

Comment: You need correlated sub-queries, i.e. condition to main query table. (Or rewrite to left joins.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function to make it.

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN att_state = 1 then att_time end) MaxTime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN att_state = 0 then att_time end) MinTime,
       person_pin,
       att_date     
FROM dbo.att_transaction 
WHERE t2.att_verify IN (4, 15)
GROUP BY person_pin,
         att_date
```

Comment: @Akii No problem glad to help

Answer (score 1):

you may try this one as well.

```
SELECT 
    person_pin AS Pin, 
    att_date AS DailyDate,
    att_state,
    time=case 
        when att_state = 1 then MIN(att_time)
        when att_state = 0 then MAX(att_time)
        end 
FROM dbo.att_transaction ATr
GROUP BY person_pin ,att_date ,att_state
WHERE att_verify IN (4, 15)
```

Comment: can't pick two correct answers ;m;..but this one works too..thank you *A*

Answer (score 0):

You have to limit your records for the aggregation to the `person_pin`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_pin AS Pin, att_date AS DailyDate,
    (SELECT MAX(att_time) FROM dbo.att_transaction WHERE att_state = 0 AND person_pin = OT.person_pin) 
    AS MaxTime,
    (SELECT MIN(att_time) FROM dbo.att_transaction WHERE att_state = 1 AND person_pin = OT.person_pin) 
    AS MinTime
FROM dbo.att_transaction OT
WHERE att_verify IN (4, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT person_pin AS Pin
        ,att_date AS DailyDate
        ,(SELECT Top 1 att_time FROM dbo.att_transaction WHERE att_state = 0 and person_pin = t.person_pin ORDER BY att_time desc) AS MaxTime
        ,(SELECT Top 1 att_time FROM dbo.att_transaction WHERE att_state = 1 and person_pin = t.person_pin ORDER BY att_time) AS MinTime

FROM    dbo.att_transaction as t

WHERE   att_verify IN (4, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

try below with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT person_pin AS Pin, att_date AS DailyDate,
max(case when att_state = 0 then att_time end) as MaxTime,
min(case when att_state = 1 then att_time end) as MinTime,
FROM dbo.att_transaction
WHERE att_verify IN (4, 15)
GROUP BY person_pin,att_date
```